# Using subprocess to run an executable with a flag

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked many times and i think i have read every one of them but I was unable to find an answer to my question. I am trying to run an executable file on a windows XP machine. The executable is in a series of folders.

```
C:\folder\program.exe
```

When i run the program i need to include a flag and a path.

```
program -f\path\to\file.txt
```

If I browse to the folder and run the command above using cli it works fine. I am trying to run this program from within my python script.

I have tried the both `Subprocess.popen` and `subprocess.call`, I don't seem to get any errors but the program does not execute either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what else I can try? Thanks

```
def Run(Path='\data\file.txt'):
  import subprocess, time

  cmd = '-f'+Path
  subprocess.Popen(["program", cmd, "C:\folder\\"])


def Run(Path='\data\file.txt'):
      import subprocess, time

      cmd = '-f'+Path
      subprocess.call(["C:\folder\program.exe", cmd])
```

Comment: your cli command is different to what you're doing with `subprocess.Popen`. you have an extra part to the command in your popen. it will be "program -f\data\file.txt C:\folder\\" while your cli command is only the first two bits.

Comment: You may be interested in the [sh](http://amoffat.github.io/sh/) module - away easier to use than raw subprocess.

Comment: shell=True
eg: subprocess.call(["C:\folder\program.exe", cmd], shell=True)

Using an intermediate shell means that variables, glob patterns, and other special shell features in the command string are processed before the command is run.  http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/index.html#module-subprocess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using backslashes in your strings. If you don't escape them, it will try to interpret the backslashes as escape characters. For example, your un-escaped string:

```
>>> '\data\file.txt'
'\\data\x0cile.txt'
```

Notice that `\f` gets turned into a different character. That's because if you look at the [table of escape characters](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) you will see that `\f` maps to the ASCII Formfeed (FF) character. You'll want to either escape them:

```
>>> '\\data\\file.txt'
'\\data\\file.txt'
```

or use a literal string:

```
>>> r'\data\file.txt'
'\\data\\file.txt'
```

For example, here's an attempt to rewrite your `Run` function:

```
import subprocess
import time

def Run(path='\\data\\file.txt'):
  flag = '-f%s' % path
  subprocess.call(['C:\\folder\\program', flag])
```

You should always use an absolute path when calling the program. If you only have a path relative to your script, you could construct a new absolute path with something like this:

```
import os.path
script_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
cmd = os.path.join(script_dir, '\\relative\\path\\to\\program.exe')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried your answer and I still got nothing. I also noticed that I can run the executable from the folder its in, but I cant run it from anywhere else. I added it to my PATH variable and still i cant get it to run. Could this also be an issue? Thanks

Comment: Are you specifying the full path to the program? If not, you should set the `cwd` argument to the `subprocess.call`, which tells it what directory to enter into before trying to execute the program.

Comment: Added info about the path to the answer.

Comment: I thought the third argument on the call was specifying the path. I'll change it and give it a try. Should I remove the 'C:\\folder\\' part? thanks

Comment: I assumed that was an argument to your program. Updated the answer.

Comment: Not sure if it will help but im running Python 2.5, I tried the above code and nothing happens. I also printed out the return from the subprocess and it was 0.

Comment: Sounds like your subprocess program doesn't do anything then. Try running something you know will work.

Comment: Using the script I am able to open internet explorer and other programs. It must be something with the program I'm trying to run.

Comment: Real weird, if i create a shortcut to the program and modify the target to include the flag and path it works properly. If i remove the target path from the shortcut it does not work. So i guess i have to call it like a shortcut.

Comment: Can you help me assemble a popen with a cwd, my attempts have failed

Comment: Thanks for the help, when i specified the cwd it worked as listed.